# How to implement radio group with breadcrumb view in android

Tags: android

I need to implement the horizontal radio group with the breadcrumb like view as shown below:

![image: breadcrumb view]

The problem is radio group has Linearlayout as its parent. So It puts all the radio buttons linearly. So I am not able to achieve the effect like above for checked and unchecked states of radiobuttons.

Note: I achieved it successfully when there are only 2 radio buttons with this effect. But can't handle it with more than 2.

Has anybody implemented such before? Any help will be appreciated. TIA !

Answer (score 0):

you have to use fragmentbreadecrumbs view in android from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/HanselAndGretel)